# Crystal Reports - Data missing when exporting to (PDF or excel or word)

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, crystal-reports

I'm trying to either print or export some Crystal Reports in asp.net
web application. The reports were made with CR 10.5, get their data
from an `SQL Server 2008 database.`

When I print or export to PDF, a bunch (but not all) of the fields are
skipped. I've 
confirmed that the reports work fine in the viewer and designer, but
not when trying to view or export

1) Some fields are always skipped.
2) The same fields seem to be skipped.

Any suggestion or help is appreciated.

Comment: can you find a pattern with the fields which aren't exporting? it might be fields that use "display string" or subreports (they are handled slightly differently when exporting).

Answer (score 0):

try this...

bind your crystal report viewer in **page_init()** method or check your page postback event...